VMware: Gettings task result from PowerCLI
I'm trying to report on the state of snapshot tasks in VMware, using PowerCLI. I've found a function that extends the functionality of Get-Task (Get-TaskPlus by LucD), but this won't give the expected result. I use the function in the following way:
Get-TaskPlus -User <username> -Realtime -Reverse

Although this gives results, these are all tasks from longer ago (e.g. yesterday or the day before) despite using the "-Realtime" switch.
Basically it boils down to this: how can I successfully query for the state of a snapshot task (either create or delete) that has recently been submitted, just like one would be able to see in the Vsphere Client under the tasks for a VM (state being "completed, successful, failed, etc.)?
Examples of Get-TaskPlus variants used that didn't lead to the expected result:
Get-TaskPlus -User <username> -Realtime -Reverse
Get-TaskPlus -MaxSamples 2 -User <username> -Realtime -Reverse
Get-TaskPlus -MaxSamples 1 -User <username> -Realtime -Reverse -Finish (Get-Date)
Get-TaskPlus -User <username> -Reverse -Realtime -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-5)

